# Change automatically between two div's with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

Okay, so i want these two div's to switch every third second. my question is: how should i do this in JavaScript? I want to create a strobelight effect. Please ignore minor bugs in my code, im not completely finished.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>STROBE</title>
<style>
#strobe {
    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border: 1px solid blue;

    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.06s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;

}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { background-color:green; }
    25% { background-color:#5D96FF; }
    50% { background-color:F0BE00; }
    75% { background-color:#710595; }
    100% { background-color:red; }
}

@keyframes blinker {  
    0% { background-color:green; }
    25% { background-color:#5D96FF; }
    50% { background-color:F0BE00; }
    75% { background-color:#710595; }
    100% { background-color:red; }


}

#baw {
    animation-name: bw;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border: 1px solid red;

    -webkit-animation-name: bw;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.06s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;

}

@-webkit-keyframes bw {  
    0% { background-color:black; }
    100% { background-color:white; }
}

@keyframes bw {  
    0% { background-color:black; }
    100% { background-color:white; }
}
</style>
</head>
    <body style="width:100%;height:1800px;">
        <div id="strobe"></div>
        <div id="baw";></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript timing (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

In the function you can define the visibility of each div. For example:

```
var visible = true;
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('strobe').style.visibility = visible ? 'hidden' : 'visible'; // use short if/else to decide which value to user
    document.getElementById('baw').style.visibility    = visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'; // short if/else is called ternairy
    visible = !visible; // reverse the value of itself
}, 3000);
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT: modified to get visibility with javascript (not jQuery)
EDIT by Martijn: User ternairy to shorten code a lot.

Comment: Might be better do use `style.display` with none/block if you want them on the same position. `visibility:hidden` is hidden, but will take up the space

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/v9cKg/1/

```
setInterval(
    function()
    {
        $("#strobe").toggle("slow");
        $("#baw").toggle("slow");
    },
    3000);
```

It is in JQuery, but pretty easy to convert into pure javascript.

Comment: OP has not tagged `jquery` so technically he dont want to use `jquery` i suppose

Comment: May be. But I wonder, if he doesn't know simple hide and seek in pure Javascript what he might know about JQuery. :)

Comment: Plus, he is getting to learn how to do the thing in "Write Less, Do Morw" way.

Comment: Thats something we cant comment on :)

Comment: OP here, i just started coding two days ago so i would guess there is alot of basics i dont know. Thanks for the replies anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that; (http://jsfiddle.net/geass54/p9RcF/1/)

```
    <div id="strobe"></div>
<div id="baw" style="display:none"></div>
```

and the js file

```
    var visible = true;
setInterval(function(){

    if(visible)
    {

        $('#strobe').show();
        $('#baw').hide();
        visible=false
    }else
    {
        $('#strobe').hide();
        $('#baw').show();
        visible=true
    }

},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some simple css and javascript, no need for all the animations and effects with hiding/showing things (which you dont want, those are intensive.

Just toggle a class, take a look at the following example
HTML:

```
<div id="strobeDiv" class="basicStyling">
    <h1>This is some text</h1>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
setInterval(function(){ $('#strobeDiv').toggleClass('reversedBasic') }, 3000);
```

Style:

```
.basicStyling{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
.reversedBasic{
    background: #000; /* if no change, use !important here */
    color: #FFF;
}
```

---

For the extra credits, this javascript would be better, because you save the reference to the element just once, which makes it more lightweight. If this is not done, every X ms jQuery will try to find the element (which is fast if you use ID's, but this is faster:

```
var $strobediv = $('#strobeDiv'); // save the reference global, just once
setInterval(function(){ $strobediv .toggleClass('reversedBasic') }, 3000);
```